# How to use a loop to access the word preceding a verb in a sentence, using spaCy? Python

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I use spaCy to locate verbs in sentences via POS tags, and then try to manipulate the verb. The manipulation of the verbs is dependent on a condition - for example depending on the word that precedes the verb. For example, I might want to convert this sentence - containing three verbs (does, hurt, run):

```
(1) "Why does it hurt to run very fast."
```

into this sentence:

```
(2) "It hurts to run very fast."
```

This looks straightforward to me. However, somehow my function has a problem when it encounters the same POS tag twice in the same sentence. It looks like in that case one of the IF clauses (line 13 below) is not updated, so that it evaluates as `False` while it should be `True`. I cannot figure out what I am overlooking and how to solve it. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

s = "Why does it hurt to run very fast."
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence':[s]})
k = df['sentence']

1 def marking(row):
2    L = row
3    verblst = [('VB'), ('VBZ'), ('VBP')] # list of verb POS tags to focus on
4    chunks = []
5    pos = []
6    for token in nlp(L):
7        pos.append(token.tag_) # Just to check if POS tags are handled well
8    print(pos)  
9    if "Why" in L:  
10        for token in nlp(L):
11            if token.tag_ in verblst: 
                 # This line checks the POS tag of the word preceding the verb:
12               print(pos[pos.index(token.tag_)-1]) 
13                if pos[pos.index(token.tag_)-1] == 'TO': # Here things go wrong
14                    chunks.append(token.text + token.whitespace_)
15                elif pos[pos.index(token.tag_)-1] == 'WRB':
16                    chunks.append(token.text + token.whitespace_)                                
17                else: 
18                    chunks.append(token.text + 's' + token.whitespace_)
19            else:
20                chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)                    
        L = chunks
        L.pop(0)
        L.pop(0)
        L = [L[0].capitalize()] + L[1:] 
    L = "".join(L)
    return L

x = k.apply(marking)
print(x)
```

This gives the following result:

```
"It hurts to runs very fast."  # The 's' after run should not be there

                  0      1      2      3     4     5    6     7     8
POS list of s: ['WRB', 'VBZ', 'PRP', 'VB', 'TO', 'VB', 'RB', 'RB', '.']
sentence s:     "Why   does     it   hurt   to   run   very  fast.  ."
```

The problem is caused by the fact that 'VB' is found at both index 3 and 5. It looks like the index in line 13 is not updated after the first 'VB' - which I expected to happen automatically. As a result, with the second 'VB', line 13 looks at index 2 instead of index 4. Hence, the condition in 13 is not met, and the second VB is processed in line 18 - resulting in a mistake. I am puzzled by why this happens. What am I not seeing? And how can this be solved?

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem here is that you're only looking up the index of the  `token.tag_` string value in your list of part-of-speech tag strings that you've compiled upfront. This always returns the *first* match – so in the case of "run", your script doesn't actually check the POS before index 5 (which would be `TO`), but instead, the POS before index 3 (which is `PRP`).

Consider the following abstract example:

```
test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
for value in test:
    print(test.index(value))  # this will print 0, 1, 2, 0, 4
```

A better (and potentially also much simpler) solution would be to just iterate over the `Token` objects and use the `Token.i` [attribute](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes), which returns its index in the parent document. Ideally, you want to process the text once, store the `doc` and then index into it later when you need it. For example:

```
chunks = []
doc = nlp("Why does it hurt to run very fast.")

if doc[0].text == 'Why':  # the first token's text is "Why"
    for token in doc:
        if token.tag_ in ['VB', 'VBZ', 'VBP']:
            token_index = token.i  # this is the token index in the document
            prev_token = doc[token_index - 1]  # the previous token in the document
            if prev_token.tag_ == 'TO':
                chunks.append(token.text_with_ws)  # token text + whitespace
            # and so on
```

Ideally, you always want to convert spaCy's output to plain text **as late as possible**. Most of the problems you were trying to solve in your code are things that spaCy already does for you – for example, it gives you the `Doc` object and its views `Span` and `Token` that are performant, let you index into them, iterate over tokens anywhere and, more importantly, never destroy any information available in the original text. Once your output is a single string of text plus whitespace plus other characters you've added, you won't be able to recover the original tokens very easily. You also won't know which token had whitespace attached and how the individual tokens are/were related to each other.

For more details on the `Doc`, `Token` and `Span` objects, see [this section in the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#architecture) and the [API reference](https://spacy.io/api/doc#attributes), which lists the available attributes for each object.

Comment: I do find it weird that I only get the first match when running through the list of part-of-speech tags... But your solution is great. It is also much simpler. Your rationale is also clear. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad it worked! And yes, that's just how the `list.index()` method works in Python – [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html): *"Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is x"*. So if your list contains the same string twice or more times and you look up its index, you'll get the index of the first matching item. That's also why you often want more flexible data structures that let you express complex relationships and keep exact references (especially when working with text).